# How to redirect stdin to a file?

Tags: c, linux, redirect, gcc, stdin

I want to redirect stdin to a file, so that I can write to the file and my program prints the character.
Below is a simple c code snippet, which prints stdin.

The programm is compiled with gcc and runs on debian 4.19.0 in virtualbox

```
//printchar.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int c;
    
    while( (c = getchar()) !='.') {
        putchar(c); 
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I call the programm with `./printchar 0 < testfile.txt`

Then i `echo efghi > testfile.txt` but nothing happens.
If i prefill the file with abcd, abcd is printed instantly after programm start, but again I can't echo something to the testfile.

Isn't it possible to redirect stdin in this way?

Comment: Sounds like you want a *named pipe*. [man mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo)

Comment: You can try this: `tail -f -n +1 testfile.txt | ./printchar` and `echo defg > testfile.txt` on another terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using `getchar`like this:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int c;

    while(1)
    {
      c = getchar();
      if (c == '.') break;
      if (c != EOF)
      {
        putchar(c);
      }
      else
      {
        usleep(100);
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or using `read` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  char c;
  int n;
  while(1)
  {
    n = read(0, &c, 1);
    if(n > 0)
    {
      if (c == '.') break;
      putchar(c);
    }
    else
    {
        usleep(100);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, you need to append to the file using `>>` like:

```
touch testfile.txt           // create empty file
./printchar < testfile.txt   // start program
echo hello >> testfile.txt   // append to file
echo world >> testfile.txt   // append to file
echo . >> testfile.txt       // append to file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use heredoc `<<` associated with redirection into a file like this :

```
    << keyCodeToStopWriting >> myFile
    first line
    second line
    keyCodeToStopWriting  //Stop the writing
```

In this exemple I use `>>` to add line at the end of the file but you can overwrite it with `>`